# Bootstrap split button not rendering correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7

I cannot get a Bootstrap split button to render correctly.  It works fine in Codepen and JSFiddle, but on this test Drupal website the dropdown piece seems to be getting pushed under the button. I have tried messing with all the CSS I know and even tried some suggestions from ChatGPT. Nothing worked.  I need a CSS expert at this point I guess.

You can see it here:  http://lab.oyhd.com/

Got to Menu>Infrastructure>Location Management to see it.

The Add Location button dropdown should be to the right of the button.  Here's a link to the Bootstrap example where I got the code.  You can see how they are supposed to display there.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#btn-dropdowns-split

Thanks for reading and any help you can offer.

Here is the actual code I used:

```
enter code here

<div class="split">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Add Location</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/node/add/location">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="/node/add/ct-building">Building (Campus)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/node/add/sublocation">SubLocation</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, you should really produce a [example]... that said, you have many unwanted `<br>` tag that both push the second button to a new line and increase it's height.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Added the code I used to the original post.   The <br> must be getting added by Bootstrap or Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, there are a bunch of `<br>` tags inside your button group and dropdown button. You should remove them:

**This is how it looks like in the browser:**

```html
<div class="split">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Add Location</button><br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><br>
    <span class="caret"></span><br>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span><br>
  </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="/node/add/location">Location</a></li>
<li><a href="/node/add/ct-building">Building (Campus)</a></li>
<li><a href="/node/add/sublocation">SubLocation</a></li>
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

There is also a conflict in your CSS which I couldn't resolve, but a hack on the `.btn-lg` class would solve it (I'd add a custom class and apply the rule on that instead of globally):

```css
.btn-lg {
   padding: 4px 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I tried adding that CSS but it made no difference.  BTW, I added the actual code I'm using to the original post.

Comment: Updated my answer, added the current state in the browser. Either your editor software or something in your infrastructure changes the HTML code.

Comment: Your code is identical to mine.  I believe Drupal is affecting it somehow....

Comment: Its' 'identical' because I wanted to point out the problem with, and to explain it(how it's rendered in the browser). It looks like Drupal passes it through some content filter.

Comment: Finally figured it out.  For those of you running into extra <br> tags in Drupal, I solved this problem like so:

Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats » Full HTML
Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)

This would apply to whatever text format you are using.